# How to specify AWS endpoint in AWS CLI having wildcard subdomain in endpoint DNS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-vpc

I have a vpc with private subnet running amazon linux 2 based ec2 instance. My goal is to access s3 buckets from my private instance.
I have created an endpoint interface for s3 under that private subnet. A role to access s3 from ec2 was also created and linked to my private ec2 instance.

After creating s3 endpoint interface, I have received below URLs:

- *.vpce-0baa889820078e037-k898xutp.s3.eu-west-2.vpce.amazonaws.com
- *.vpce-0baa882732078e037-k898xutp-eu-west-2b.s3.eu-west-2.vpce.amazonaws.com

I am not sure how to specify them in aws cli after parameter --endpoint-url. If I use them like

`aws s3 ls --endpoint-url *.vpce-0baa889820078e037-k898xutp.s3.eu-west-2.vpce.amazonaws.com`, as obvious it throws an error as below:

*Bad value for --endpoint-url "*.vpce-0baa889820078e037-k898xutp.s3.eu-west-2.vpce.amazonaws.com": scheme is missing.  Must be of the form http:/// or https:///*

If I make it as `aws s3 ls --endpoint-url http://vpce-0f3a882732078e037-g4l8xutp.s3.eu-west-2.vpce.amazonaws.com`, it results in timeout error. If I use https instead http, it displays below error:

SSL validation failed for https://vpce-0f3a882732078e037-g4l8xutp.s3.eu-west-2.vpce.amazonaws.com/ hostname 'vpce-0baa889820078e037-k898xutp.s3.eu-west-2.vpce.amazonaws.com' doesn't match either of 's3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com', 'bucket.vpce-0baa889820078e037-k898xutp-eu-west-2a.s3.eu-west-2.vpce.amazonaws.com', '*.accesspoint.vpce-0baa889820078e037-k898xutp-eu-west-2b.s3.eu-west-2.vpce.amazonaws.com', '*.control.vpce-0baa889820078e037-k898xutp.s3.eu-west-2.vpce.amazonaws.com', '*.control.vpce-0baa889820078e037-k898xutp-eu-west-2b.s3.eu-west-2.vpce.amazonaws.com', '*.accesspoint.vpce-0baa889820078e037-k898xutp.s3.eu-west-2.vpce.amazonaws.com', '*.accesspoint.vpce-0baa889820078e037-k898xutp-eu-west-2a.s3.eu-west-2.vpce.amazonaws.com', '*.control.vpce-0baa889820078e037-k898xutp-eu-west-2a.s3.eu-west-2.vpce.amazonaws.com', '*.bucket.vpce-0baa889820078e037-k898xutp-eu-west-2a.s3.eu-west-2.vpce.amazonaws.com', 'bucket.vpce-0baa889820078e037-k898xutp-eu-west-2c.s3.eu-west-2.vpce.amazonaws.com', '*.bucket.vpce-0baa889820078e037-k898xutp-eu-west-2b.s3.eu-west-2.vpce.amazonaws.com', 'bucket.vpce-0baa889820078e037-k898xutp-eu-west-2b.s3.eu-west-2.vpce.amazonaws.com', '*.s3-control.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com', '*.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com', '*.bucket.vpce-0baa889820078e037-k898xutp-eu-west-2c.s3.eu-west-2.vpce.amazonaws.com', '*.accesspoint.vpce-0baa889820078e037-k898xutp-eu-west-2c.s3.eu-west-2.vpce.amazonaws.com', '*.bucket.vpce-0baa889820078e037-k898xutp.s3.eu-west-2.vpce.amazonaws.com', '*.s3-accesspoint.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com', 'bucket.vpce-0baa889820078e037-k898xutp.s3.eu-west-2.vpce.amazonaws.com', '*.control.vpce-0baa889820078e037-k898xutp-eu-west-2c.s3.eu-west-2.vpce.amazonaws.com'

I am unable to understand how to consume it, I was watching few videos where the demonstrator had just a plain URL without wildcard (*) at the subdomain.

Need help please.

Comment: When you run the aws s3 ls  command with endpoint-url do you doit from your computer or a ec2 in the vpc? And do you know that s3 has gateway endpoints for s3?

Comment: Yeah I forgot to add, I am running it from an EC2 instance based on amazon linux. Yes I am aware of s3 gateway but I want to give a try for s3 endpoint interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what AWS says about it:

> The following image shows the VPC console Details tab, where you can find the DNS name of a VPC endpoint. In this example, the VPC endpoint ID (vpce-id) is vpce-0e25b8cdd720f900e and the DNS name is *.vpce-0e25b8cdd720f900e-argc85vg.s3.us-east-1.vpce.amazonaws.com. Remember to replace * when using the DNS name. For example, to access a bucket, the DNS name would be bucket.vpce-0e25b8cdd720f900e-argc85vg.s3.us-east-1.vpce.amazonaws.com. You can also append the name of your bucket to the start of the URL. For example, if you wanted to access my-bucket the URL would be my-bucket.bucket.vpce-0e25b8cdd720f900e-argc85vg.s3.us-east-1.vpce.amazonaws.com.

Link to page:
[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/privatelink-interface-endpoints.html#types-of-vpc-endpoints-for-s3:~:text=PrivateLink%20Guide.-,Accessing%20buckets%20and%20S3%20access%20points%20from%20S3%20interface%20endpoints,vpce%2D0e25b8cdd720f900e%2Dargc85vg.s3.us%2Deast%2D1.vpce.amazonaws.com.,-For%20more%20about](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/privatelink-interface-endpoints.html#types-of-vpc-endpoints-for-s3:%7E:text=PrivateLink%20Guide.-,Accessing%20buckets%20and%20S3%20access%20points%20from%20S3%20interface%20endpoints,vpce%2D0e25b8cdd720f900e%2Dargc85vg.s3.us%2Deast%2D1.vpce.amazonaws.com.,-For%20more%20about)

CLI command:
aws s3 --region us-east-1 --endpoint-url https://bucket.vpce-1a2b3c4d-5e6f.s3.us-east-1.vpce.amazonaws.com ls s3://my-bucket/

Comment: Omg, I was literally on that page link few times while trying to understand difference between gateway and interface but never scrolled down. Thank you @Erik